# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Notification plugin 'cannot find symbol' issues

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

**Error**:
platforms/android/app/src/main/java/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Options.java:626: error: cannot find symbol

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

*Not sure how to fix this. Please help. Tried several options that others suggested without success.*

**Ionic Info**:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.14.1 (/home/chandra/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.7
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.7
@angular/cli                  : 9.1.7
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.3
native-run  : not installed

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/chandra/Android/Sdk)
NodeJS            : v12.22.1 (/home/chandra/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/node)
npm               : 6.14.12
OS                : Linux 5.8

**java and javac versions**: 1.8.0_292

Comment: I tried by removing the local-notification cordova plugin and tried building APK and the same error is appearing with another plugin ..(like below). `platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CameraLauncher.java:801: error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: Some more output. Not sure if the issue is with **Gradle** `* What went wrong:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
 https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_lineBUILD FAILED in 3s
22 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 21 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/chandra/Public/advocase-mobile/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/chandra/Public/advocase-mobile/platforms/android/build.gradle
`

Comment: Solved this with the help of a friend. This error is occurring because of a missing JAR file. I added **cordova-plugin-androidx** and **cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter** plugins and built the APK successfully.